# Can I use any other flavor instead of vanilla in Copycat Sonic shake Recipe?

Tags: flavor, ice-cream, drinks

I have reviewed various recipes for **[copycat sonic shake recipe](http://www.foodpinup.com/drinks/copycat-sonic-shakes/)** and they all use vanilla flavor.  But I don't like vanilla flavor. Can I add any other flavor to it?

Comment: Why would you want to use a copycat recipe, if you don't like the item being copied?

Comment: Are you trying to mimic a flavor they actually make, other than vanilla? It does look like they have a lot of other flavors: http://www.sonicdrivein.com/MenuSection/frozen-zone/real-ice-cream-shakes People can certainly make suggestions for one of them, if you tell them what flavor you actually want.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Your question is being downvoted mostly because it's a little unclear. The answer seems like an obvious "yes!" It's your shake, do with it what you want. Are you asking for a replacement that is similar to vanilla? Or are you maybe asking if it will still taste like a Sonic shake?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. It won't be a copycat anymore, but it's still a smoothie. You can add any flavor that appeals to you. Vanilla is entirely optional.

Comment: It might still be a copycat if it's for one of Sonic's other flavors, but the OP certainly wasn't clear if that was the intent.